# Data text field displaying as system.Byte in radiobutton list

Tags: mysql, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list and i am binding it with a combination of two column as data text field.BUt it is displaying as system.Byte for data text field.It is working fine on local but on hosting it is not working.I am using Mysql driver3.51 and vb.net

```
            query="SELECT CONCAT (`desc` ,'- ' , `price`)  AS     `title`,desc  FROM   `ping`"
            db.cmd.CommandText = query
            Dim da As New OdbcDataAdapter(query, db.conn)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)

            r.DataSource = ds
            r.DataTextField = "title"
            r.DataValueField = "desc"
            r.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually nothing is wrong in above query .Its all about mysql concat function that was causing the problem.I have provided links that will solve the issue.
http://techclubdotnet.blogspot.in/

Answer (score 0):

```
query="SELECT CAST(CONCAT ('desc' ,'- ' , 'price') AS CHAR) AS 'title', desc  FROM 'ping'"
```